# Push notification doesn't work in production

Tags: ios, push

I've released an update of my app where I enabled push notifications. While developing the feature, everything worked fine. If I open the app, I can see on server db that the registration page was accessing. If I use the App Store version, nothing happens, nor was the callback `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is called.

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
 // build the url ...

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
}
```

All this works fine with the development version, but with the build downloaded form App Store I can't touch the url (the records are not added).

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please provide more information.  Did you switch everything over to your production certificates instead of the sandbox ones?  Are you sure your production app is hitting `[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert]`?  Did you implement `application: didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:`, and is it getting called?

Comment: mmmm the code is the same but works in development; maybe certificates issue!?